# Copy-Item throws AccessDenied exception

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files from a remote server to my base machine using powershell. This throws an 'Access Denied' exception even though the drives get mapped:

```
New-PSDrive -Name source -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\SERVERNAME1\D$\Temp\Folder" ;
New-PSDrive -Name target -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $destinationRemotePath ;
Copy-Item -Path  source:\$($file).zip -Destination target: -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop -Force ;
```

**Approach 2**

I am mapping the source drive and using `PsSession` for target drive but I get

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'source' does not exist.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Following is the code being used:

```
$Username = "UserName";
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $Password)
$session = new-pssession -computername 'TargetServerName' -credential $cred 
New-PSDrive -Name source -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\SERVERNAME1\D$\Temp\Folder" ;
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item -Path  $($args[0]) -Destination $($args[1]) -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop } -ArgumentList source:\$($file).zip,'D:\Folder' ;
```

Comment: how do you create your `PSSession`? Do you use CredSSP?

Comment: @restless1987: I have edited the question and added that section to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues on that second example:

1. The PSSession has a different scode, it does not know about your PSDrive.
2. PSSessions do not support authentication to network location like you might be used to from RDP-Sessions. See `CredSSP` or ' PSSession double hop'

*Approach 1* looks like you have no access to that share you want to use. You can specify credentials via `-Credential` parameter at `New-PSDrive`. Can you `Get-Childitem` on `Source:` and `Target:`?